# Simple redirect in IIS7 to another page?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, redirect

We are taking our website offline for approx an hour today and I want to redirect all traffic to an offline default page I created within the folder "offline" and the file is default.aspx. I tried using IIS7  HTTPRedirect by checking "Redirect requests to this destination;" and entering in the URL "http://webtest.ipam.ucla.edu/offline" but I am receiving a "Internet Explorer cannot display webpage" error.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming as you're on IIS7 that your app is in ASP.NET - if not, please ignore this:

There's a nifty little feature that if you place an app_offline.htm file in the root directory of your ASP.NET application, it will have the net effect of taking your application offline.

What is the detail you see in your "Internet Explorer cannot display webpage" error?  Is it really that generic or do you get some detail?

**Addendum**

An alternative is to add something like this into the web.config of your asp.net app (which *will* allow dynamic pages:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://myurl.com/offline.aspx" />
</system.webServer>
```

The issue with using this approach is while you're uploading new assemblies, there is a chance your application will crash when someone hits it (giving them confusing errors) while you're making changes. Consequently, the offline.aspx page may not show properly - your mileage may vary, but this is why it's generally considered a better practice to use app_offline.htm.

Comment: can I use an app_offline.aspx file instead? we have a master file that all our pages go to and the top wants us to keep it that way even if our site is down?

Comment: If I use Redirect Behavior "Only redirect requests to content in this directory" it works fine until I manually enter a known URL then it takes me to the page I requested

Comment: @mattgcon No, the purpose of taking the app offline is so that you can upload/modify .net files on the server, thus nothing asp.net will function while an app_offline.htm exists and your app is offline.  So you'd have to manually code it to include the content of the master file.

Comment: No worries - sorry it doesn't quite do what you were hoping, but it's the "correct" way (according to the almighty MS) to do this ;)